# PHP regex - Find the highest value

Tags: php, regex

I need find the highest number on a string like this:

Example

```
<div id='pages'>
 <a href='pages.php?start=0&end=20'>Page 1</a>
 <a href='pages.php?start=20&end=40'>Page 2</a>
 <a href='pages.php?start=40&end=60'>Page 3</a>
 <a href='pages.php?start=60&end=80'>Page 4</a>
 <a href='pages.php?start=80&end=89'>Page 5</a>
</div>
```

In this example, I should get 89, because it's the highest number on "end" value.

I think I should use regex, but I don't know how :(

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: `regex` isn't going to do enough for you. It can match anything you like. It can even locate all the numbers and get them into a collection for you. But ultimately, you'll need to do a max function on the collection (with possible string-to-int conversion in between) to get to the final answer.

Comment: I tried to use preg_replace to get only the final numbers on any link, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first extract all the numbers from the links then apply max function:

```
$str = "<div id='pages'>
 <a href='pages.php?start=0&end=20'>Page 1</a>
 <a href='pages.php?start=20&end=40'>Page 2</a>
 <a href='pages.php?start=40&end=60'>Page 3</a>
 <a href='pages.php?start=60&end=80'>Page 4</a>
 <a href='pages.php?start=80&end=89'>Page 5</a>
</div>";

if(preg_match_all("/href=['][^']+end=([0-9]+)[']/i", $str, $matches))
{
    $maxVal = max($matches[1]);
    echo $maxVal;
}
```

Comment: `$str = "<div>href='send=32174987409873214'</div>";` [matches this regex](http://regexr.com?34vp7).

Comment: do you think that he's gonna find the string that you've just posted? its simple he's extracting values not validating them. plus its not gonna happen. if he found anything wrong with the pattern he can simply add more to it and make it more strict.

Comment: Yes, let's all just assume "it's not gonna happen" and hope for the best. What about different `<a>` tags with `end` params in their attributes? Or `<a>` tags outside of the `<div>`?

Comment: I've been working with regex for 7 years now and I've never seen such case. so the situation you posted its never gonna happen. not even in the dream..

Comment: @RobinVanPersi nick's comments are related to this answer. Your answer is fragile, whereas DOM parsing is robust. Also, please refrain from asking people to mark your answer as the solution. The OP can make up their own mind.

Comment: @RobinVanPersi The OP was asking for a way to identify the highest value for the `end` querystring parameter in the `href` attributes of those anchors. All of the answers on this page accomplish this goal. However, your answer (and to some extent mine) impose unnecessary constraints on the input, whereas nick's answer is robust, and can handle cases such as the order of the parameters being reversed.

Comment: It's obvious the OP is trying to solve a very particular problem.  They know what the page is going to look like.  Parsing the HTML is overkill and much harder to read (which is saying a lot, being compared to regex).  If you use the absolute most robust solution to every single problem, even when it's not needed, sure you'll have a solid app but it'll also be very heavy.  Consider each situation independently and intelligently.

Comment: Moreover, rather than attempting to parse the querystring using the same regular expression, merely match the `href` attribute value, and use `parse_str(parse_url($href, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query)` to parse the querystring. I would favor XPath anyways.

Comment: @JMTyler *"They know what the page is going to look like"*. Where are you getting this information? We do not know what the OP's use case is, but from the looks of the HTML it looks like they're scraping a web page, which is when you have to be the *most* careful about what you assume. Parsing the HTML takes all of 9 lines in nick's implementation, which is 4 more lines than this answer.

Comment: @Asad If they're scraping someone else's page and that someone decides to change how this snippet looks, no solution (not even the HTML parser) can save them.  As RobinVanPersi said, the regex can always be strengthened if it's not unique enough, but the probability of that being required is remarkably low.  If you can give me a _reasonable_ example where this regex could fail (as opposed to the contrived and virtually impossible example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719713/php-regex-find-the-highest-value/16720046#comment24072827_16720046)), I will concede.

Comment: @JMTyler If the page author merely decides to add another parameter to the href attribute (I would hardly say this is a contrived situation), the regex approach becomes unusable. Parsed HTML doesn't.

Comment: nobody cares, the OP has decided which is the best solution for him.. he gave specific string and I worked based on that string. if he has more issues he would've probably posted them. no need to assume. the case is closed.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be doing this with a regex. In fact, I don't even know how you would. You *should* be using an HTML parser, parsing out the `end` parameter from each `<a>` tag's `href` attribute with [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str), and then finding the [`max()`](http://php.net/max) of them, like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $str); // All & should be encoded as &amp; 
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc);
$end_vals = array();
foreach( $xpath->query( '//div[@id="pages"]/a') as $a) {
    parse_str( $a->getAttribute( 'href'), $params);
    $end_vals[] = $params['end'];
}
echo max( $end_vals);
```

The above will print `89`, as seen in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/x1QMDk).

Note that this assumes your HTML entities are properly escaped, otherwise `DOMDocument` will issue a warning.

One optimization you can do is instead of keeping an array of `end` values, just compare the max value seen with the current value. However this will only be useful if the number of `<a>` tags grows larger.

**Edit:** As DaveRandom points out, if we can make the assumption that the `<a>` tag that holds the highest `end` value is the last `<a>` tag in this list, simply due to how paginated links are presented, then we don't need to iterate or keep a list of other `end` values, as shown [in the following example](http://viper-7.com/pDXsCa).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $str); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc);
parse_str( $xpath->evaluate( 'string(//div[@id="pages"]/a[last()]/@href)'), $params);
echo $params['end'];
```

Comment: You could use `htmlspecialchars` to convert html entities before you send it in. Something like this `htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars_decode($str))`.

Comment: @Asad - Yup, left it up to the OP to decide on that

Comment: You should XPath for `//div[@id='pages']/a[last()]/@href` to just get the specific attribute value you are interested in. OP seems to be extracting values from pagination links, it's a pretty safe assumption the one you are interested in will always be the last one in the list.

Comment: @DaveRandom Hey Dave! That's a good point, I just didn't want to make that assumption. I'm going to edit that into the answer though and put up a demo of it

Answer (score 2):

To **find the highest number in the entire string**, regardless of position, you can use

- [`preg_split` — Split string by a regular expression](http://php.net/preg_split)
- [`max` — Find highest value](http://php.net/max)

**Example ([demo](http://eval.in/31382))**

```
echo max(preg_split('/\D+/', $html, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)); // prints 89
```

This works by splitting the string by anything that is *not a number*, leaving you with an array containing *all the numbers in the string* and then fetching the highest number from that array.

Comment: As this is string input you might want to cast the result to `(int)`.

Comment: Very clean and interesting, never thought of that before :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getHighest($html) {
    $my_document = new DOMDocument();
    $my_document->loadHTML($html);
    $nodes = $my_document->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $numbers = array();

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if (preg_match('\d+$', $node->getAttribute('href'), $match) == 1) {
            $numbers[]= intval($match[0])
        }
    }

    return max($numbers);
}
```